# Как проверить изменился ли объект javax.swing.text.StyledDocument?

Tags: java, swing

Как проверить изменился ли объект javax.swing.text.StyledDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить `DocumentListener` с помощью метода [addDocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.html#addDocumentListener(javax.swing.event.DocumentListener)).